# Aggregate result group objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Where I arrived was this I needed to put the user data on the athele:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5963c6aa1aaf2c1c702ea86f"), 
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-10T18:25:46.941+0000"), 
"createdAt" : ISODate("2017-07-10T18:25:46.933+0000"), 
"name" : "athleta01", 
"nickname" : "01", 
"email" : "aaaa@terra.com.br", 
"birthday" : ISODate("1986-09-15T03:00:00.000+0000"), 
"gender" : "0", 
"disable" : false, 
"deletedAt" : false, 
"profile" : [
    {
        "departament" : ObjectId("5963c6281aaf2c1c702ea86c"), 
        "profession" : "athlete", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5963c6aa1aaf2c1c702ea870")
    }
], 
"photo" : null, 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
```

}

doc Athlete:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5963c6aa1aaf2c1c702ea871"), 
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-10T19:53:08.285+0000"), 
"createdAt" : ISODate("2017-07-10T18:25:46.948+0000"), 
"position" : "atacante", 
"shirt" : NumberInt(15), 
"document" : "87956421345", 
"weight" : "10.5", 
"height" : "2.73", 
"profileId" : ObjectId("5963c6aa1aaf2c1c702ea870"), 
"disable" : false, 
"deletedAt" : false, 
"device" : {
    "activityLevel" : "vai atuazliar", 
    "maxHeartRate" : NumberInt(45), 
    "reposeHeartRate" : NumberInt(90), 
    "codSensor" : "1a2s4e1s"
}, 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
```

}

Already tried to make the exit with the project and to set up a group also I did not have the result that I expected. I think I'm missing out on some point.

```
db.users.aggregate(
[
    {
      $match: {
        "profile.departament" : ObjectId("5963c6281aaf2c1c702ea86c")
      }
    },

    {
        $lookup: {
            "from" : "institution",
            "localField" : "profile.departament",
            "foreignField" : "departament._id",
            "as" : "user_departament"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from" : "athlete",
            "localField" : "profile._id",
            "foreignField" : "profileId",
            "as" : "athlete_departament"
        }
    },

    {
        $unwind: {
        path: "$athlete_departament",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },

    {
        $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "athlete_departament.profileId",
        foreignField: "profile._id",
        as: "username",
        }
    },

    { 
        $group: {
          _id: { name: "$user_departament.name", cnpj: "$user_departament.cnpj", photo: "$user_departament.photo"},
          departaments: {
            $push : "$user_departament.departament"
            },
          athletes: {
            $push : '$athlete_departament',
          }
        }
    },

    {$unwind : "$departaments"}, 
    {$unwind : "$departaments"}, 
    {$unwind : "$_id.name"}, 
    {$unwind : "$_id.cnpj"}, 
    {$unwind : "$_id.photo"},
    {$unwind : "$athletes"}, 
    {$unwind : "$athletes"}, 


    {
      $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        departaments : {$addToSet : "$departaments"},
        athletes : {$addToSet : "$athletes"}
      }
    },

    { "$project": {
        //_id : { name: "$_id", departaments: { $concatArrays: [ {$arrayElemAt: [ "$departaments", 0 ]}, "$profiles", "$athletes"  ] }}
        _id : { institution: "$_id", departaments: { info: "$departaments", profiles: "$profiles", athletes: { username: "$username", athlete: "$athletes" },  }}
        //_id : { name: "$_id", departaments: { "departament": { $concatArrays: [ { $arrayElemAt: ["$departaments", 0]}, "$athletes"  ] }}}
        //_id : { name: "$_id", departaments: { $concatArrays: [ {$arrayElemAt: [ "$departaments", 0 ]}, "$profiles", "$athletes"  ] }}
    }},

    {$unwind : "$_id.departaments.info"},
    {$unwind : "$_id.departaments.info"}
]);
```

Comment: You should instead post the  original source documents from their respective collections  and the desired result you want to obtain from them. Posting your "partial" result really does not tell people much about the original structure.

Comment: What I can not do and put the user inside department and athlete inside its user

Comment: What I am telling you is "your question is unclear" because you do not supply the source documents for `institution` or the related `users` or `athelete`. If you ["Edit your question"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45199680/edit) to include this information, then people have the required data in order to reproduce your desired result. So "Edit the question" and include those documents.

Comment: Sorry, I now put the documents pure, just leave what I'm trying to do in the final result